# Как извлечь версию .exe файла

Tags: c++

В проекте производится запуск внешнего приложения. Необходимо проверить, та ли версия внешней prog.exe запускается. Для начала вроде как надо извлечь версию из атрибутов prog.exe, чтобы затем сравнить её с записанным значением.
Нашел вариант кода получения версии файла в C++ Builder и пытаюсь переделать его для IDE Code::Blocks (компилятор MinGW):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

String __fastcall TForm1::GetVer(String FileName)
{
String Version;
DWORD h;
DWORD Size = GetFileVersionInfoSize(FileName.c_str(), &h);
if (Size == 0)
{
    Version = L"неизвестно";
    return Version;
}

TCHAR *buf;
buf = (TCHAR *)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, Size);
if (GetFileVersionInfo(FileName.c_str(), h, Size, buf) != 0)
{
    PVSFixedFileInfo ValueBuf;
    UINT Len;
    if (VerQueryValue(buf, L"\\", &(void *)ValueBuf, &Len) != 0)
        Version = String().sprintf(L"%d.%d.%d.%d",
        HIWORD(ValueBuf->dwFileVersionMS),
        LOWORD(ValueBuf->dwFileVersionMS),
        HIWORD(ValueBuf->dwFileVersionLS),
        LOWORD(ValueBuf->dwFileVersionLS));
}
GlobalFree(buf);
return Version;
}
```

Что не хватает для компиляции?

Comment: Кто ж знает-то, если вы даже текст ошибки не привели...

Comment: *"переделать его для IDE Code::Blocks"* -- а как IDE влияет на результат? Тут, скорее, в компиляторе дело, а не в "нескучных обоях". В любом случае ни проблема, ни диагностика не указаны вообще, без них и сказать нечего.

Comment: error: expected initializer before 'String'|

Comment: Э... А вы уверены что mingw известно про `String`?

Comment: Нет. Также не знает __fastcall и TForm1.Потому и спросил, может кто уже встречал конкретные проблемы при смене компилятора.

Comment: А как это соотносится с текущей постановкой вопроса? Советую отредактировать его и сформулировать реальные проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. А как он помогает разобраться в проблеме? - Текущая постановка вопроса предельно ясна в преамбуле.

Comment: Хеш - это традиционно. И красиво. Но этот код получается раз в 5 больше основной программы. Как-то не уютно после такого...

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Совершенно непонятная строка. Что она должна делать?

2) `MinGW` ничего не знает про `String`. Замените на что-то более переносимое, начиная от простого `wchar_t` и заканчивая `std::string`.

3)

```
String __fastcall TForm1::GetVer(String FileName) {
```

Это - реализация какой-то сущности, которая у вас отсутствует, и для решения задачи не нужна вообще. Опишите обычную функцию:

```
static ваш_строковый_тип GetVer(ваш_строковый_тип FileName) {
```

Comment: 1. Это обязательная (стандартная) строка MinGW.  2. MinGW точно также не знает wchar_t и std::string.  3. Видел несколько примеров C++ Builder и во всех есть такая строка (с некоторыми вариациями).

Comment: @Creative 1) Да что вы говорите! Если для вас это "стандартная строка", которую нужно лепить куда ни попадя совершенно бездумно, то начать стоит с учебника по C. 2) `wchar.h`, `string` и пр. там нет в стандартных заголовках?

Comment: 1. Да, это стандартная строка для консольных приложений. Извините, что сразу не уточнил. Подумал, что Вы должны знать, коль решили помочь разобраться в MinGW.  2. Демонстрирую: |error: expected initializer before 'wchar'| Это, как понимаю, говорит о том, что компилятору чего-то не хватает. Вот об этом изначально и есть мой вопрос.

Comment: @Creative, по обоим пунктам могу повторить: начните с учебника начального уровня. Вы просто не понимаете что говорите.

Comment: по обоим пунктам могу порекомендовать: начните с изучения MSDN Microsoft. Для примера: "Специальная функция с именем main — это начальная точка выполнения для всех программ на языках C и C++. Синтаксис объявления функции main выглядит следующим образом: int main(); ".    
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6wd819wh.aspx
По второму пункту сами найдёте - будет полезно.  У Вас есть что ответить по существу? Нет? - Не занимайтесь словоблудием.

Comment: @Creative, MinGW - это порт GCC  на WIndows для компиляции POSIX приложений, цитировать MSDN при портировании приложений  - все равно что цитировать коран в синагоге. main() -  точка входа в _любую_ программу. Компилятору не хватает заголовкрв , естественно. У вас синтаксическая ошибка - либо это прототип и строка должна заканчиваться точкой с запятой, либо у вас не описано тело функции. Если ваша программа использует майкрософтский MFC или борландовский набор классов для GUI - они не портируемы на linux

Comment: @Swift, улыбнуло... Вы же сами сразу после "синагоги" тут же почти процитировали MSDN. Не? Я о том, что и Вы ничего другого не сказали. Так что MSDN - он и в Африке MSDN. А вот когда чел в ответе (не в комменте - в ОТВЕТЕ!!!) во первЫх строкАх на полном серьёзе несёт ахинею - это уже не комильфо. Похоже на то, что уверовал в свою непогрешимость. Иначе бы постеснялся давать ответ с полным отсутствием полезности и не скатывался бы в комментах на менторский тон.   По сути. Что компилятору чего-то не хватает - было понятно сразу, однако ни от кого ничего конкретного не прозвучало. Жаль...Аут...

Comment: @Creative, ахинею тут несёте вы. Но у вас просто слишком мало знаний чтобы это понять.

Comment: @Creative  Я процитировал не MSDN а стандарт ISO, если не знаете что он регламентирует, считайте, что С++ вы не изучали. a) ваш код неверно сформирован - это раз, или вы выкинули что-то из текста. в  вашей строке синтаксическая ошибка. b)  MinGW - не Borland,  это GNU C++ компилятор, __stdcall, _fastcall в нем никогда не будут поддерживаться. В приципе их можно выкинуть через #define, с)  Не хватает вам порта  VCL библиотеки, которого для  MinGW не существует

Comment: @Swift. Вот что процитировал я из MSDN: "Специальная функция с именем main — это начальная точка выполнения для всех программ на языках C и C++." Вот что процитировали Вы: "main() - точка входа в любую программу." Комментировать не буду, места мало.  В части заданного вопроса. Ваш последний ответ единственный, в котором по делу и конкретно объяснены причины ущербности кода. Спасибо. Если бы он был первым, то обсуждение пошло бы совсем в другом русле. Данный пример показал, что пытаться тупо переделывать код компилятора MinGW в Borland бывает глупо. Проще взять три API и написать код с нуля

Comment: @Creative проще использовать API\framework который  работает и там и там. Например OSG или Qt

Comment: @Swift, Спасибо за совет. Qt со временем возможно и понадобится. Сейчас решил поступить по-другому. Упорно повозившись с GCC, неожиданно напоролся и на явный баг, к тому же из-за его ограниченности понял, что это был не лучший выбор. А потому установил Builder, и сразу стало веселее. Без особых хлопот сделал функцию, решающую поставленную задачу. Прекрасно работает. Поскольку это будет не по теме (компилятор другой), то приводить код здесь не стал.

Comment: @Creative явных багов там мало, часто за баги принимают UB или отличие в диалектах (gcc поддерживает два разных стандарта, по ключу)